# Validation error with simple-schema

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to insert an array into an object and I'm not having any luck. I think the schema is rejecting it based on validation but I'm not sure why. If I `console.log(this.state.typeOfWork)` and check `typeof` it states its an `Object` which contains:

```
(2) ["Audit - internal", "Audit - external"]
0: "Audit - internal"
1: "Audit - external"
```

My collection after an update contains:

```
"roleAndSkills": {
    "typeOfWork": []
  }
```

Example: `Schema`

```
roleAndSkills: { type: Object, optional: true },
  'roleAndSkills.typeOfWork': { type: Array, optional: true },
  'roleAndSkills.typeOfWork.$': { type: String, optional: true }
```

Example: `update`

```
ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
      $set: {
        roleAndSkills: {
          typeOfWork: [this.state.typeOfWork]
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your entire update call and collection schema?

Answer (score 0):

`typeOfWork` is an `Array`. You should push your value in it :

```
$push: {
    "roleAndSkills.typeOfWork": this.state.typeOfWork
}
```

for multiple values :

```
$push: {
    "roleAndSkills.typeOfWork": { $each: [ "val1", "val2" ] }
}
```

[mongo $push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

[mongo dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty`

Comment: Double quotes doesn't return an error, however, it also doesn't add in the array. No error.

Comment: Do you try to push one or multiple values ?

Comment: multiple. see my console.log in the original post

Comment: In theory, this should work, however, $each doesn't work. I've posted a separate question relating to this and `.map`. I'll update here if I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple schema has some problems with validation on Objects or Arrays, i had the same problem in a recent app i developed.

What can you do?
well, what i did, on the Collections.js file, when you are saying:

```
typeOfWork:{
  type: Array
}
```

Try adding the property blackbox:true, like this:

```
typeOfWork:{
  blackbox: true,
  type: Array
}
```

This will tell your Schema that this field is taking an Array, but ignore further validation.

The validation i made was on main.js, just to be sure i had no empty array and the data was plain text.

As requested here is my update method, im my case i used objects not arrays but it works the same way.

```
 editUser: function (editedUserVars, uid) {
      console.log(uid);
      return Utilizadores.update(
        {_id: uid},
        {$set:{
          username: editedUserVars.username,
          usernim: editedUserVars.usernim,
          userrank: {short: editedUserVars.userrank.short,
          long: editedUserVars.userrank.long},
          userspec: {short: editedUserVars.userspec.short,
          long: editedUserVars.userspec.long},
          usertype: editedUserVars.usertype}},
        {upsert: true})

    },
```

here it the collection schema

```
UtilizadoresSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 username:{
    type: String
 },
 usernim:{
    type: String
 },
 userrank:{
    blackbox: true,
    type: Object
 },
 userspec:{
    blackbox: true,
    type: Object
 },
 usertype:{
    type: String
 }
});
Utilizadores.attachSchema(UtilizadoresSchema);
```

Hope it helps

Rob

Comment: Trying this but not having any more luck. How did you write the update method?

Comment: Nope. Simpleschema is driving me nuts.

Comment: @bp123 can you log "this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId" and see if you are getting the ID on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You state that `this.state.typeOfWork` is an *array* (of strings) but then when you `.update()` your document you are enclosing it in square brackets:

```
ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
  $set: {
    roleAndSkills: {
      typeOfWork: [this.state.typeOfWork]
    }
  }
});
```

Simply remove the redundant square brackets:

```
ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {
  $set: {
    roleAndSkills: {
      typeOfWork: this.state.typeOfWork
    }
  }
});
```

Also since your array is just an array of strings you can simplify your schema a bit by declaring it as such with `[String]` for the type:

```
'roleAndSkills.typeOfWork': { type: [String] }
```

Note furthermore that objects and arrays are by default optional so you can even omit the optional flag.

Comment: Yeh, I tried that ages ago. For some reason, it doesn't work. Arrays really have me confused.